# Smalltalk change variable value

Tags: gnu-smalltalk

I'm learning Smalltalk, but I didn't found any example of how change variable value.
How can I do it?

```
Object subclass: test [
    | testvar |

    "setvalue [
        Function to change value of variable 'testvar'
    ]"

    getvalue [
        ^testvar
    ]
].

Test := test new.
"
How i can set value to testvar?
Transcript show: Test getvalue.
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use so-called *keyword-messages*.
You end a method with a colon and put the variable name after that (probably multiple times).

So if you have something like `methodFoo(a, b, c)` in a curly-brace language, in Smalltalk you typically write

```
methodFoo: a withSomething: b containing: c
```

or likewise. This can make method names more readable, too!

Also, getters and setter in Smalltalk typically are named after the variable they are representing.
(And classes are typically capitalized while variables are not)

So your example would turn into

```
Object subclass: Test [
    | testvar |

    testvar: anObject [
        testvar := anObject.
    ]

    testvar [
        ^testvar
    ]
].

test := Test new.
test testvar: 'my value'.
test testvar print.
" prints 'my value' "
```

Comment: You might consider accepting this answer if it has helped you :)